# Fedora 25 first DNS lookup times out

Tags: fedora, dns

Not sure where to begin, but recently my DNS lookups have become extremely slow, always 5 seconds. After running `strace ping -c 1 google.com` I noticed that the first DNS lookup always times out:

```
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(5, FIONREAD, [56])                = 0
recvfrom(5,         "a\322\201\200\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\6google\3com\0\0\34\0\1\300\f\0\34"...,     2048, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53),     sin_addr=inet_addr("8.8.8.8")}, [28->16]) = 56

>>>
>>> Timeout happens here
>>> poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4960
>>> )  = 0 (Timeout)
>>>

poll([{fd=5, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=5,     revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(5, "\361\226\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\6google\3com\0\0\1\0\1", 28,     MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 28
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(5, FIONREAD, [44])                = 0
recvfrom(5,     "\361\226\201\200\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\6google\3com\0\0\1\0\1\300\f\0\1"...,     2048, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53),     sin_addr=inet_addr("8.8.8.8")}, [28->16]) = 44
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 4958) = 1 ([{fd=5,     revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(5, "a\322\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\6google\3com\0\0\34\0\1", 28,     MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 28
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4958)  = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(5, FIONREAD, [56])                = 0
recvfrom(5,     "a\322\201\200\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\6google\3com\0\0\34\0\1\300\f\0\34"...,     65536, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53),     sin_addr=inet_addr("8.8.8.8")}, [28->16]) = 56
close(5)
```

Am I reading the `strace` correctly? What could be happening here?

Running Fedora 25.

Comment: IPv6 problems maybe?

Comment: You were right. adding `options single-request-reopen` to my `/etc/resolv.conf` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `options single-request-reopen` to my `/etc/resolv.conf` resolved the issue!